# React too many re-renders on if else statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, rendering, use-state

I'm trying to use setState to change the value currentTheme whenever the program notices that theme, which is a state stored in App.js changes to a specific value. I am getting this error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Not too sure what to do here, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
   import React, { useState } from "react";
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import Editor from "./Editor";
    import { monokai, solarizedDark, terminal, textmate } from "./ui/themes";


const CodeContainer = ({ setHtml, setCss, setJs, setRenderDoc, theme }) => {
  const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState(monokai);

  if (theme === "textmate") {
    setCurrentTheme(textmate);
  } else if (theme === "solarized_dark") {
    setCurrentTheme(solarizedDark);
  } else if (theme === "terminal") {
    setCurrentTheme(terminal);
  } else {
    setCurrentTheme(monokai);
  }

  return (
    <Container style={currentTheme}>
      <Editor
        setHtml={setHtml}
        setRenderDoc={setRenderDoc}
        languageName="html"
        theme={theme}
      />
      <Editor
        setCss={setCss}
        setRenderDoc={setRenderDoc}
        languageName="css"
        theme={theme}
      />
      <Editor
        setJs={setJs}
        setRenderDoc={setRenderDoc}
        languageName="javascript"
        theme={theme}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CodeContainer;

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 40vh;
  border-bottom: 4px #211e1c solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 12px 15px;
`;
```

Comment: you need to wrap your if statements inside an useEffect that listens your theme to avoid running the setCurrentTheme on every render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you need a state for it. Make a function like this, and if theme change, it will get the correct currentTheme for you.

```
const getTheme = (theme) => {
  if (theme === "textmate")
      return textmate;
  if (theme === "solarized_dark") 
      return solarizedDark;
  if (theme === "terminal") 
      return terminal;
  return monokai;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
<Container style={getTheme(theme)}>
```

Alternatively, you can calculate the theme inline using local variables:

```
const CodeContainer = ({ setHtml, setCss, setJs, setRenderDoc, theme }) => {
  let currentTheme = monokai;
  if (theme === "textmate") {
    currentTheme = textmate;
  } else if (theme === "solarized_dark") {
    currentTheme = solarizedDark;
  } else if (theme === "terminal") {
    currentTheme = terminal;
  }

  return (
    <Container style={currentTheme}>
    //...
  )
}
```

Comment: @RyanHaraki This or something like it is best. The prop and state in the original question are written to stay in lock step with eachother, which is a sure sign that the prop should be used directly, not copied into state. Copying into state results in extra code complexity, and a performance penalty due to double rendering.

Comment: Good point, thanks. The code works just as well and as you said is even faster since there is no double rendering. I will mark this as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mention in the comment the problem is that you're running that on every render and react notices that and prevents the application to run.

You can leverage the use of the useEffect hook which is a hook that is used to listen to value changes and do side effects according those changes, it replaces all the lifecycle methods in the class based components.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (theme === "textmate") {
    setCurrentTheme(textmate);
  } else if (theme === "solarized_dark") {
    setCurrentTheme(solarizedDark);
  } else if (theme === "terminal") {
    setCurrentTheme(terminal);
  } else {
    setCurrentTheme(monokai);
  }
}, [theme])
```

The first argument is a callback that is going to run whatever logic you want to do when the theme value changes, and the second argument is an array that is used to tell the useEffect when to run, so in this case we pass the theme prop and it will tell the hook to run everytime the value changes.
This is the documentation for it if you want to learn more things you can do about it:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html